# What's the difference between x-www-browser and gnome-www-browser?

Tags: browser, default-browser, update-alternatives

What's the difference between x-www-browser and gnome-www-browser?
I came across it here: [Setting the default browser when update-alternatives fails](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/ubuntu-default-browser.html).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both are scripts that, when configured by `update-alternatives`, call the default application for internet browsing on a GUI environment.

The script `x-www-browser` calls the application configured to run on any desktop environment that runs under X Server, while `gnome-www-browser` application configured specifically calls for GNOME. Similarly, `www-browser` is a script to call the default browser on a TUI ([text-based user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)) environment, such as `w3m` or `elinks`, for example.

1. You can check which browser they are associated with the commands

   ```
   update-alternatives --display x-www-browser
   update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser
   ```
2. To list all the alternatives to these scripts, use

   ```
   update-alternatives --list x-www-browser
   update-alternatives --list gnome-www-browser
   ```
3. To configure a default browser, use the commands

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
   sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
   ```

Since these scripts can call different browsers, it may happen that a certain program call a browser other than the default browser. This often causes confusion for some users, but this issue can be fixed by running the command `sudo update-alternatives --config` as explained in item 3, above.

Sources:

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/91
- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-customizing.en.html
- http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives

Comment: Thanks for a nice sum-up! Additionally, to install a new alternative (just before 3), use `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /opt/firefox/firefox 100` (and the same for `x-www-browser`).